# Linked List implementation using Javascript

Tags: javascript

me and my partner have an issue. in the addToTail method we end by reassigning veryEndResult to newNode (veryEndResult = newNode).

What we were actually trying to do is reassign the value of veryEndResult (this.head.next) to newNode, is there a way to do this? We couldn't google it either because we don't really know how to go about forming that question.

Would love if an experienced coder could help us out on this.

```
class LinkedList {
  constructor () {
    this.head = null;
    this.length = 0;
  }
  
  addToHead (data) {
    const newNode = new LinkedListNode(data, this.head);
    this.head = newNode;
    this.length ++;
    return true;
  }

  addToTail (data) {
    const newNode = new LinkedListNode(data, null);
    let test = ['this','head'];
    this.length ++;
    for (let i = 0 ; i < this.length - 1 ; i++) {
      test.push('next');
    }
    let endResult = test.join('.');
    let veryEndResult = eval(endResult);
    console.log(endResult);
    veryEndResult = newNode;
  }
}
  
class LinkedListNode {
  constructor (value, next) {
    this.value = value;
    this.next = next;
  }
}

let linkedList = new LinkedList();

linkedList.addToHead(20);
linkedList.addToTail(30);
```

Comment: `let veryEndResult = eval(endResult);` Please don't do this...ever. There are use cases for `eval` but they are exceptionally few. This isn't one of them.

Comment: we figured by the comments of where we found eval :D

eval = evil, unfortunately didn't know how to "unstring" it any other way. After joining them

Comment: Side note: your use of the verb "assign" is confusing. When you have `a = b`, then `b` is assigned to `a`, not vice versa. (see your first phrase)

Comment: That's [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You don't need to go through strings *ever* for this. It's just `let curr = this.head; for(let i = 0; i < this.length - 1; i++) { curr = curr.next; }` Or can even be done with a `while` loop which terminates when `curr.next === null`

Comment: you are right @trincot just noticed, my bad would be vice versa in this case